# How do I get a title from default.master to other content pages?

Tags: asp.net, .net

My front folder has a default.Master page and some other aspx files like login.

default.Master:

```
<%@Master language="C#" CodeBehind="~/default.Master.cs" Inherits="Front._default"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="General" %>

<html>
<head>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-165741164-1"></script>    
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-165741164-1');
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server" />
    Mytitlewebsite
</title>      
</head>
```

Im trying to set "Mytitlewebsite" as the default title for all my contents page. How do I do this and set it?

So for example my login.aspx is like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Front.Login" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Front" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="General" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

<title>PortfolioOne™ Login</title> //i dont want this title, i want the title from default.Master

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your login page isn't currently setup to utilize a master page. Your page directive doesn't reference a master page. It should look something like the code sample below. The easiest way to ensure everything that is needed is there is to readd the page and make sure you specifically create the page with a master page.

Example of what it would look like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/default.master" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Front.Login" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Front" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="General" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle">
 <!-- Whatever you want in your title -->
</asp:Content>
```

Note master pages don't have everything specified like `<html>`, `<head>`, etc. That is all covered by the master page. It is primarily just your content placeholders. On another note, I've never seen a content place holder used in the page title before. I'm not saying it won't work, but It seems really odd. If the page title is static you should be able to set it to what you want and it will display as expected as long as you don't change it.